# SQL join tables show empty field if record doesn't exist

Tags: sql, join, null, left-join

I'm in need of help.

I need to join two doubles

Table 1

```
Product_Name Content_Type Price
 Movie         Adult       10
 Movie         Kids        10
```

Table 2

```
Product_Name Content_Type Rating
 Movie         Adult        A
 Movie         Kids         B
 Movie         Romance      C
```

I need to join the tables so that it looks like this

Desired Output

```
 Product_Name Content_Type Price Rating
   Movie         Adult      10     A
   Movie         Kids       10     B
   Movie         Romance           C
```

Current Output

```
 Product_Name Content_Type Price Rating
   Movie         Adult      10     A
   Movie         Kids       10     B
   Movie         Romance    10     C
```

Current Query

```
select * from table2 left join table1 on table2.Product_Name=table1.Product_Name
```

In actual fact, in the real table there are many values for Product_Name.
I wrote the query like that with this logic in mind,

Look for all rows in table2, find a match in table1 and join the rows. If there is a row in table2, but no row in table1, then only show table2's value while showing Null for the corresponding fields in table1.

Comment: add AND content_type in the join clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't get the record with the content type Romance if you just join on the product_name. You need to join on content_type as well:

```
select *
from table2 left join
     table1
     on table2.Product_Name=table1.Product_Name and
        table2.content_type = table1.content_type
```